# iOS - Prevent object deallocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, memory-management

I have an object, similar to `UIAlertView` that presents a dialog box with a custom message and title.  So far, the following code works to show the dialog box:

```
DialogBox *dialog = [[DialogBox alloc] initWithMessage:@"Hello" delegate:self];
[dialog showDialog];
```

When I tap either the 'YES' or 'NO' buttons on the dialog box, however, the app crashes because the `DialogBox` instance has been deallocated.

Making the *dialog instance variable a property fixes this, but this wouldn't work for me because I'd want to be able to randomly create `DialogBox` instance variables.

Is there a way to keep the *dialog instance variable "alive" until I want it to actually disappear from view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Crash log below:

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000005f7b5e7d

VM Regions Near 0x5f7b5e7d:
    MALLOC_TINY            000000000ea00000-000000000eb00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000008fea8000-000000008fedb000 [  204K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: performSelector:withObject:withObject:
iPhone Simulator 369.2, iPhone OS 6.1 (iPhone/10B5126b)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x010e60b0 objc_msgSend + 36
1   UIKit                           0x0001c2c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
2   UIKit                           0x0001c258 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
3   UIKit                           0x000dd021 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
4   UIKit                           0x000dd57f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
5   UIKit                           0x000dc6e8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
6   UIKit                           0x0004bcef -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 846
7   UIKit                           0x0004bf02 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
8   UIKit                           0x00029d4a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 436
9   UIKit                           0x0001b698 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
10  GraphicsServices                0x01bf2df9 _PurpleEventCallback + 339
11  GraphicsServices                0x01bf2ad0 PurpleEventCallback + 46
12  CoreFoundation                  0x01c0cbf5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
13  CoreFoundation                  0x01c0c962 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
14  CoreFoundation                  0x01c3dbb6 __CFRunLoopRun + 2118
15  CoreFoundation                  0x01c3cf44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
16  CoreFoundation                  0x01c3ce1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
17  GraphicsServices                0x01bf17e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
18  GraphicsServices                0x01bf1668 GSEventRun + 104
19  UIKit                           0x00018ffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
20  DialogApp                       0x0000257d main + 141 (main.m:16)
21  DialogApp                       0x000024a5 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x998580ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9214904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92148e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92130cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x998589ca kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x049fec2b _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x049fe8cc _dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x998580ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9214904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92148e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92130cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x998580ee __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9214904c _pthread_workq_return + 45
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92148e19 _pthread_wqthread + 448
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92130cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:: WebThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x998557d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x99854cb0 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x01c38a49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
3   CoreFoundation                  0x01c3d8d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
4   CoreFoundation                  0x01c3cf44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x01c3ce1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   WebCore                         0x0356dc50 RunWebThread(void*) + 608
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92146557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92130cee thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x5f7b5e7d  ebx: 0x0001c26e  ecx: 0x00cb6b07  edx: 0x00005240
  edi: 0x012cfd4f  esi: 0x694c534e  ebp: 0xbfffe108  esp: 0xbfffe0d4
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0x010e60b0   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x5f7b5e7d
Logical CPU: 1
```

Comment: Where is the crash happening ? In the delegate method ?

Comment: The buttons have selectors that point to methods within the DialogBox class, and it looks like there are errors when those methods are called because the object has been deallocated.

Comment: Can you put the crash log ?

Comment: Try to declare your dialog box in .h and then alloc init in viewDidLoad and then use wherever you required.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the (relatively rare) situations where you want to keep a reference to `self` in order to prevent deallocation.  This will make your dialog box "fire and forget" without it being deallocated.

In your `DialogBox` class, add a **strong** property (it should be a private one) where you can store a reference.  Let's call it `selfProperty`.

Then, when you initialize your class, use `self.selfProperty = self;` and set it to nil when you want to be deallocated.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a `@property (nonatomic, strong) id selfProperty` property that I set to `self` when I initialised DialogBox, but the deallocation error still appears when I select one of the dialog buttons.

Comment: @lnafziger Why a property and not an ivar?

Comment: @achiral: Are you sure that your initialization function was called?  Set a breakpoint and make sure.

Comment: @Richard: You could use either, as long as a strong reference is kept.  Using properties is a "best practice" though, and helps when you need to change things down the road.

Comment: @lnafziger But there's no such thing as a "private" property, so anything but a readonly property doesn't seem helpful; and I don't know how ARC would implement a readonly property that returns self.

Comment: @Richard: A "private" property is simply a declared property that is not in the public header file so people won't know about it.  Usually it goes in a class extension at the top of the .m file.